# Data Access Library: What to return if access isn't allowed or data isn't found?

Tags: c#, architecture, data-access-layer, privileges

---

I'm building a DAL for a widget-based reporting application, its been designed in such a way that users pick, configure and deploy reporting 'widgets' to their home screens. Widgets can report across various kinds of company data - sites, brands, employees and so on.

Whilst all users can access all the widgets/reports, all users are not authorised to access all data. If I work for Company-A I can't view sales reports for Company-B or staff attendance data for a salesman at Company-C, however I *can* configure such a report and add it to my 'dashboard'.

At runtime, an intermediate 'DataService' class has the job of checking the user's credentials and, if access is permitted, returning the appropriate object collection to the client.

On the initial build I just returned an empty List if access to the data was not allowed, but this is also what I do if no data is returned by the report (which can happen). I'd like to show an 'Access Denied' message on the front end if the user isn't authorised to view the data but obviously if all I get back in either eventuality is an empty collection its impossible to know if this was because of insufficients rights or just no data.

I'd be grateful if you could suggest a way of coding around this, my first thought was to move the credential-checking into another object which in turn calls the data access class but time constraints mean this isn't an option.

The only thing I can think of, which goes against everything I've ever learnt, is to throw a custom exception e.g. InsufficientApplicationPrivilegeException if access isn't granted, but this smells bad.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I think if you were to consider the DAL as a seperate entity and imagine that it was your sole responsibility whilst all consumers was work done by a third party, you would probably raise an exception for Access Denied - most of the framework would.  If however, you want to avoid _exception logic_ it would be helpful to provide functions to help the consumers determine if they have sufficient access to data - though that sounds like more of a business logic issue, which is it that controls the access?

Comment: I would have liked to make authorisation a separate step but as I've mentioned its all going to have to be done in one pass. In this scenario do you think I could justify breaking the rule about exceptions only being used when things go wrong rather than as a way of controlling program execution?

Another concern is that everyone in the organisation will have my widgets on their dashboards, given the high-visibility, performance is a major factor. I'm using aggressively cached data, but have concerns about the high relative cost of throwing exceptions. Do you have a view on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a couple of options. One is to make a composite object that your data service class returns. The composite object looks something like this: -

```
class DataResult<T>
{
   IEnumerable<T> Data;
   Result ServiceResult;
}
```

ServiceResult contains metadata about the outcome of your service call - it could be an enum which contains e.g. Success, AuthenticationFailure etc. etc.. You can then switch on this in order to do different behaviour.

An alternative option might be to use the NullObject pattern that shows a single item of data in the view which instead of real data simply shows "Access Denied" for the display properties of the object. The advantage of this approach is that your front-end doesn't need to have any conditional logic etc.; however if you want to show a specific message box or similar rather than just displaying a dummy row of data in your widget, then this probably isn't appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll take a look at the NullObject pattern, but at the moment the composite object method looks like it might be quickest and easiest. Is the NullObject a convention in the world of DAL-building for this sort of problem?

Comment: You can use NullObject where you essentially want to treat a null object (or in your case, an empty list caused by authentication failure) in the same way as you would do for getting "real data" back. So you don't have to have lots of if (!myList.Any()) calls everywhere etc. because the "null object" and real one act in the same way (in your case, display some text into a widget control).

In your case I think that the composite pattern is a better option though; it's more flexible as you can extend the ServiceResult and add more metadata on in future if required.